# Network configuration query for configuring second router as Wi-Fi extender using WDS

Tags: networking, router

I am software professional and very limited technical knowledge about networking. I am trying to set a second router as Wi-Fi extender without LAN cable. My primary router is Tenda Model F3 (Which is connected to ISP provider by LAN) by PPPoE. My secondary router is Tplink 1D06

My primary router (Tenda) configuration is as follows

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 2E-09-E9-CE-64-E1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::68bd:41bc:e4fd:726e%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, April 6, 2022 8:43:58 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, April 7, 2022 8:44:01 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 154012137
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-03-00-01-2E-09-E9-CE-64-E1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

   Security Mode : Mixed WPA/WPA2 - PSK
   IP Address : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server enable : Yes
   IP range : 192.168.0.100
              192.168.0.150



I have done following steps on my secondary router TP-Link



   1. Reset the router to factory defaults
   2. Login to TP link router using 192.168.0.1 ( default IP and connected to TP-LINK_1D06 Wi-fi )
   3. Change LAN IP Address to 192.168.0.130
   4. Enable WDS bridge and connect to my Tenda Primary router using scan and given same password as it is in Tenda Router using channel option Auto
   5. Disable DHSCP Server 
   6. Reboot both routers
```

I am able to connected to primary router without any issue but my second router (TP-Link) always showing "No internet Secured." I have tried many times but same issue

Can you pl help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved For my second router I had given an IP 192.168.0.2 and connect to primary router TENDA address.

Thanks